# If $Q$ is a trace class operator on $U$, then each bounded, linear operator from $U$ to $H$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator from $Q^{1/2}U$ to $H$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let

- $U$ and $H$ be Hilbert spaces
- $Q$ be a bounded, linear, nonnegative and symmetric operator on $U$ with finite trace
- $U_0:=Q^{1/2}U$
- $L$ be a bounded, linear operator from $U_0$ to $H$

> I want to show that $$\left\|L\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U_0,H)}^2\le\left\|L\right\|_{\mathfrak L(U_0,H)}^2\operatorname{tr}Q\;,\tag 1$$ where
>
> - $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U_0,H)}$ denotes the [Hilbert-Schmidt norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) for bounded, linear operators from $U_0$ to $H$
> - $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{\mathfrak L(U_0,H)}$ denotes the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) for bounded, linear operators from $U_0$ to $H$
> - $\operatorname{tr}$ denotes the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class#Definition) of a bounded, linear operator on $U$

Let $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of $U$ with $$Qe_n=\lambda_ne_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N$$ for some $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. We can show that $$\tilde e_n:=\sqrt{\lambda_n}e_n\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N$$ is an orthonormal basis of $U_0$. Thus, $$\left\|L\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U_0,H)}^2\stackrel{\text{def}}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|L\tilde e_n\right\|^2=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lambda_n\left\|Le_n\right\|^2\tag 2\;,$$ where $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|$ denotes the norm on $H$.

> How do we need to proceed in order to obtain $(1)$ from $(2)$?

Comment: $$\|Le_n\|^2≤\|L\|^2\cdot \|e_n\|^2$$ and $$\sum_n \lambda_n = \sum_n e_n^* (Q e_n)=\rm{tr}(Q)$$furthermore $\lambda_n$ are all $\geq0$ from $Q$ being a positive operator